# How do I make an exit handler that runs after all weakref finalizers run

Tags: python, weak-references, atexit

I have a module meant to be consumed as a library by other programs.  I am using `weakref.finalize` to register cleanup functions for these objects, and `atexit.register` for some top level cleanup.  I need all of the object finalizers to run *before* the top level cleanup.

The structure looks something like this:

```py
#module.py
from weakref import finalize
import atexit

class MyObject:
    @staticmethod
    def _cleanup():
        print('Cleaning up module object')
    
    def __init__(self):
        finalize(self, MyObject._cleanup)

def _cleanup():
    print('Cleaning up module')

atexit.register(_cleanup)
```

Looking at the source code of `weakref`, weakref registers an atexit handler as soon as one finalizer is created.  This means that, in the case of the example module, the top-level cleanup will run after all the finalizers *only if* nothing else has created a finalizer by the time module has been imported.

```
#user_code.py
from weakref import finalize

class UserObject:
    @staticmethod
    def _cleanup():
        print('Cleaning up user object')

    def __init__(self):
        finalize(self, UserObject._cleanup)

do_user_object = False
if do_user_object:
    u = UserObject()
   
import module
m = module.MyObject()
```

if `do_user_object  = True` the output is:

```
Cleaning up module
Cleaning up module object
Cleaning up user object
```

if `do_user_object  = False` the output is:

```
Cleaning up module object
Cleaning up module
```

So the cleanup order is dependent on user actions.  How can I make the top-level cleanup always run after all of that module's objects are finalized?

Comment: As I understand it, finalizers are guaranteed to run before any global variables such as modules are cleaned up. 
 If you want to check if the finalizer has run, you can save the return value of weakref.finalize to an instance variable (such as `self._finalizer`).  Then you can check `self._finalizer.alive` to see if the finalizer has been run yet or not.
 
Info completely stolen from https://youtu.be/IFjuQmlwXgU?t=479 which is really helpful channel for Python topics. Hopefully he'll do a full vid on weakref soon.

Comment: @nigh_anxiety finalizers are guaranteed to run before any global variables are cleaned up, but I need them to also run before my atexit callback runs.
Checking the alive status of one of the finalizers would tell me which of the 2 situations shown in the question I'm in, but then I would also need a way to correct that situation if the atexit callback is running but none of the finalizers have.

Comment: I am not set on using atexit, but I need some way to make something run after those finalizers.  One idea I had was to make a dummy object with a finalizer, and register it forst, but is there something less ugly?

Comment: Yeah, I see that changing usercode.py so that `import module` is at the top of the routine will cause the module to always be cleaned up last, but there's no way to force the user to do that - plus in more complex code there could be other things calling finalizer before your module ever gets imported.

Comment: I played around a bit and I think this might work, but I haven't tested every scenario.
In module.py, I replaced the `atexit.register()` line with `finalize(_cleanup, _cleanup)`, and then the order of the cleanup operations was always 1) Module Object, 2) Module, 3) User Object.  Maybe setting a finalizer for the cleanup function or a dummy object at the top of the module would be best as finalizers run FILO.

Comment: @nigh_anxiety This should work.  Registering the function as it's own finalizer works and is simpler than a dummy object, but it's still a hack :/. Would appreciate if you wrote that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

weakref.finalize also uses atexit.register().  When the first instance of the finalize class is initialized, it checks if the class has been registered with atexit, and adds an entry for the classmethod finalize._exitfunc() if it has not.  That class cleanup method then processes all of the finalize objects in the reverse order of how they were created.

Cleanup actions registered with atexit are also run in the reverse order of how they were registered.

As a result, if any other code calls weakref.finalize before your module is loaded, your cleanup function set with atexit.register will always be execute after all of the finalize code.

The solution is to instead log your module's cleanup code with weakref.finalize as well. If your module creates any instances of it's own classes that will have cleanup functions, than the module cleanup code should be sent to finalize before any of those objects are created.  This will guarantee the module cleanup runs after the finalize code for each of your module objects.
Here's an example of a valid module level call to finalize that is linked to the cleanup function itself:

```
# module.py
from weakref import finalize


class MyObject:
    @staticmethod
    def _cleanup():
        print('Cleaning up module object')

    def __init__(self):
        finalize(self, MyObject._cleanup)


def _cleanup():
    print('Cleaning up module')

finalize(_cleanup, _cleanup)
```

Then if `do_user_object = True`, the example above will get the output:

```
Cleaning up module object
Cleaning up module
Cleaning up user object
```

For reference of anyone that needs it, other object types that are valid for weakref are listed in the documentation here:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/weakref.html

Comment: `finalize(_cleanup, _cleanup)` this looks like a refcycle to me.